# how to set text of Edit Control to float value?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to set the string value of an  `Edit Control` to a value of a float number. So I'm first converting the float to a string, then I'm calling `SetDlgItemText`:

```
        fvalue = 0.123;
        wchar_t szBuff[100];
        wsprintf(szBuff, L"%f", fvalue );
        SetDlgItemText(m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT1, szBuff);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get a stack overflow error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I ended up doing it:

```
wchar_t buf[256];
LPCTSTR pszFormat = TEXT("%4.4f");
StringCbPrintf(buf, sizeof(buf), pszFormat, fvalue );
SetDlgItemText(m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT1, buf);
```